# The page is getting reset on submitting form after a while in HTML, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, https

In the HTML page I am creating, I have two url inputs. One for website and one for Image url. The link and the image at the url will be displayed. But when I submit, the page resets after few seconds after displaying the result. I am attaching my minimum reproducible code here. When only one of the inputs is https then it works not otherwise. Why it is behaving like this. There is no error also.
HTML file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>demo</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<body>
<form>
<label for="Website" >Website</label>
<input type="url"  id="Website" >
<label for="ImageLink" >Image Link</label>
<input type="url"  id="ImageLink" >
<button type="submit"  onclick="displayDetails()" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<table id="display">
<tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Image</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The script is as follows: 
script.js:

```
var row  = 1;
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.addEventListener("submit",displayDetails);

function displayDetails(){
var website = document.getElementById('Website').value;
var imageSrc = document.getElementById('ImageLink').value;
var display = document.getElementById("display");
var Row = display.insertRow(row);
var cell = Row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = Row.insertCell(1);
web = website.link(website);
cell.innerHTML =  web ;
img  =  document.createElement("img");
img.src = imageSrc;
cell2.appendChild(img);
row++;
}
```

If i enter random website name without https, then it works but not when both are valid https sites.

Comment: What do you expect `website.link(website);` to do?

Comment: Just display link as active link. Not as string

Comment: I replaced it by creating anchor tag and even tried removing https and then using it. Again same problem

Comment: A form without an action defined submits to the same page. You'd need to use [`.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the form from doing its default submit action.

Comment: When I use prevent default. The required output is not obtained. I mean I want to dynamically update table on same page. Which doesn't work if i use .preventDefault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because whenever a form is submitted, a refresh event is triggered by default. You have to prevent this behavior. Update your code as follows.

Pass in parameter `event` to your function.

```
<button type="submit onclick="displayDetails(event)" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Also, you have to update your JavaScript function as follows

```js
function displayDetails(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var website = document.getElementById("Website").value;
  var imageSrc = document.getElementById("ImageLink").value;
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  var Row = display.insertRow(row);
  var cell = Row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = Row.insertCell(1);
  web = website.link(website);
  cell.innerHTML = web;
  img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imageSrc;
  cell2.appendChild(img);
  row++;
}
```

Notice that the parameter `event` is received as `e` and the default behaviors are prevented by `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks! It works. I have doubt that why it happened only when both urls were valid and not when only one was valid.

Comment: Please [don't suggest inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these), give the right example and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

1. [String.prototype.link()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) is deprecated. Simply use the `<a>` tag.
2. What is `web` in your code? Why you define `onclick` in html AND add event listener in js? Things like this will give you weird problems sooner or later.
3. The button in your form submits the form, thus navigates to url. Simply add `event.preventDefault()` or move the buton outside of the form.

```js
var row = 1;
var xyz = document.getElementById("xyz");
xyz.addEventListener("click", (event) => displayDetails(event));

function displayDetails(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var website = document.getElementById("Website").value;
  var imageSrc = document.getElementById("ImageLink").value;
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  console.log(website, imageSrc, display)
  
  var row = display.insertRow(row);
  var cell = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  
  const aTag = document.createElement('a');
  aTag.href = website;
  aTag.innerText = website;
  cell.appendChild(aTag);
  
  img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imageSrc;
  cell2.appendChild(img);
  
  console.log(display)
  
  row++;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="Website">Website</label>
  <input type="url" id="Website">
  <label for="ImageLink">Image Link</label>
  <input type="url" id="ImageLink">
  <button id="xyz">Submit</button>
</form>

<table id="display">
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think adding this code will solve your problem
event.preventDefault();

```
submit.addEventListener("submit",(event)=>{
event.preventDefault();
// your function displayDetails code});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).